# SQL Order By - Show certain records last

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sorting

I want to list my products in sorted by price from low to high, but I also want out of stock products show after products that have quantity.  I'm not sure how to do that with an `ORDER BY`

Here is my current query, I want to add something to show out of stock products last:

```
SELECT * FROM products WHERE cat_id='$cat_id' ORDER BY price LIMIT $start,$record
```

Comment: Use two queries.

Comment: @Sammitch if i use two query i can't make correct pagination for that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `CASE` statement in your `ORDER BY`:

```
ORDER BY CASE WHEN quantity <> 0 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END, price
```